# Structure a String List in Objects with Items (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, object, tstringlist

after long Time I have a new questions. Hope that somebody can help me.

I have a String-List which I want to convert and structure to Objects. The Data Sets of the String List looks like following:

```
"23092014 Peter available"
"23092014 David available"
"23092014 Lisa available"
```

What I want are Objects with the parameters Date, Name and status instead of a long string. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: `String.Join` and simple LINQ query (or even a loop if you're not familiar with LINQ) is all you need. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have no Idea, how to do this. Do you have a little codesnippe for orientation ?

Comment: This is a very simple thing to do so I suggest that you show us an attempt.  `String.Split` will separate the data items and you should be able to take it from.